# How to maintain instance of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i created multiple fragment in MainActivity.I called the fragment using Switch case.So every time new instance is created.How to maintain the same instance?Here my code:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new Fragment1();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Fragment2();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new Fragment3();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new Fragment4();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new Fragment5();
        break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: This sounds like something a ViewPager would do using a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: So check out this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
Fragment fragment = null;

fragment = new Fragment1()
fragment = new Fragment2()
```

store fragments in separate variables:

```
Fragment fragment1 = null;
Fragment fragment2 = null;

fragment1 = new Fragment1()
fragment2 = new Fragment2()
```

...

and only create new objects if variable is `null`